# Second order homogeneous differential equations: why do repeated roots modify the solution set?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following differential equation with constant coefficients:
$$
y'' + 2ky' + k^2y = 0 \, .
$$
The auxiliary equation is
\begin{align}
m^2 + 2km + k^2 &= 0 \\[4pt]
(m+k)^2 &= 0 \\[4pt]
m &= -k \, .
\end{align}
This means that the solutions of the differential equation are $Ae^{-kx}+B\color{red}{x}e^{-kx}$, where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants. The $x$-term highlighted in red is what confuses me. Generally speaking, if the roots of the auxiliary equation are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then the solutions to the differential equation are $Ae^{\alpha x} + Be^{\beta x}$. However, if $\alpha=\beta$, then the solutions are not $Ae^{\alpha x} + Be^{\alpha x}$—or at least, this solution is incomplete. I can verify that $y=xe^{-kx}$ is a solution of the differential equation by plugging it back in to the equation, but I'm looking for a deeper reason for why this occurs.

Comment: note that $Ae^{\alpha x}+Be^{\alpha x}=Ce^{\alpha x}$ with $A+B=C$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think I understand what you're saying. So $y=Ce^{\alpha x}$ is one of the solutions to the differential equation, but we need another term to find the entire solution set. I'm still unsure about why the term with the $x$ in it appears, though.

Comment: The set of solutions is a vector space with dimension $2$. If you have a double root for the characteristic equation, on only have a vector of the basis of the set of solutions, so you have ti find another one. This is usually found by the method of variation of the constant, and one finds this solution.

Comment: we know there must exist two linearly  independent solutions

Comment: The fundamental solution set must be linearly independent so that any solution you can create is a result of any linear combination from the the solutions in the fundamental set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$y'' + 2ky' + k^2y = 0 \, .$$
$$(y' + ky)' + k(y'+ky) = 0 $$
$$((y' + ky)e^{kt})' = 0 $$
Is equivalent to:
$$(ye^{kt})''=0$$
Inetgrate twice and the solution will be obvious.

Comment: $$ye^{kt}=At+B \, .$$Hence, $y=(At+B)e^{-kt}$! Thank you. I have one question: how did you 'know' how to manipulate the equation to give this result? Is there a deeper theory or method that underlies this?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes thats corect your integration is correct. i don't know any theorie about this. It's just that this second order linear diferential equation  with repeted root can easily be integrated this way. @Joe

Comment: Aryadeva: see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3958865/second-order-homogeneous-differential-equations-why-do-repeated-roots-modify-th/3959223#3959223), where I have seeked to generalise your solution to all second order homogeneous differential equations w/ constant coefficients :-)

Answer (score 6):

Taking inspiration from [Aryadeva's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3958865/second-order-homogeneous-differential-equations-why-do-repeated-roots-modify-th/3958893#3958893), I have found a direct method of solving the differential equation
$$
y'' + by + cy = 0
$$
which takes into account what happens when you have a repeated root. This equation has the auxiliary equation
$$
m^2+bm+c=0 \, .
$$
Say $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the auxiliary equation. Then, the equation can be rewritten as
$$
(m-\alpha)(m-\beta)=0
$$
which implies that $b=-(\alpha + \beta)$ and $c=\alpha\beta$. Then, the original equation can be rewritten as
$$
y'' -(\alpha+\beta)y' + \alpha\beta y =0 \, .
$$
It can then be directly shown that
\begin{align}
y&=Ae^{\alpha x}+Be^{\beta x} \quad\text{if $\alpha\neq\beta$} \\[4pt]
y&=(A+Bx)e^{\alpha x} \quad\text{if $\alpha = \beta$} \, .
\end{align}
Here is how:
\begin{align}
y'' -(\alpha+\beta)y' + \alpha\beta y &= 0 \\[6pt]
y'' - \alpha y' - \beta y' + \alpha\beta y &= 0 \\[6pt]
y'' - \alpha y' - \beta (y' - \alpha y) &= 0 \\[6pt]
(y'' - \alpha y')e^{-\beta x} - \beta (y' - \alpha y)e^{-\beta x} &= 0 \\[6pt]
\left[(y' - \alpha y)e^{-\beta x}\right]' &= 0 \\[6pt]
(y' - \alpha y)e^{-\beta x} &= B \\[6pt]
y' - \alpha y &= Be^{\beta x} \\[6pt]
e^{-\alpha x}y' - \alpha e^{-\alpha x}y &= Be^{(\beta - \alpha)x} \\[6pt]
\left[e^{-\alpha x} y \right]' &= Be^{(\beta - \alpha)x}
\end{align}
Suppose that $\alpha \neq \beta$. Then, the following manipulations are justified:
\begin{align}
e^{-\alpha x}y &= \int Be^{(\beta - \alpha)x} \, dx = \frac{Be^{(\beta - \alpha)x}}{\beta - \alpha} + A\\[6pt]
y &= \frac{B}{\beta - \alpha}e^{\beta x} + Ae^{\alpha x} \, .
\end{align}
But then, since $\frac{B}{\beta - \alpha}$ is just some arbitrary constant, we may relabel it as $B$. We are left with
$$
\boxed{
\;\\[4pt]
\quad y=Ae^{\alpha x}+Be^{\beta x} \quad
\\
}
$$
as expected. If $\alpha = \beta$, then the above reasoning is invalid since we end up with division by zero. Instead,
$$
e^{-\alpha x}y = \int Be^{(\beta - \alpha)x} \, dx = Bx + A
$$
and therefore
$$
\boxed{
\;\\[4pt]
\quad y = (A+Bx)e^{\alpha x} \, . \quad
\\
}
$$

Comment: Nice. Thank you for this Jie (+1)

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters point out, we *know* that there must be two independent solutions, even without knowing what they are. It is a sensible guess to try something like $xe^{-kx}$. An algorithmic way to find that this is the correct factor is to use [variation of parameters](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx).

Indeed, you may find it illuminating to transform the equation by making the substitution $y = e^{-kx}v$ and deriving the equation for $v$.

There are many direct ways of interpreting this change in the solution set. One way is by making small perturbations. Indeed, suppose we had solutions $k_\pm = -k \pm \varepsilon$. Then we get independent solutions $y = Ae^{(-k-\varepsilon)x} + Be^{(-k+\varepsilon)x} = e^{-kx}(Ae^{-\varepsilon x} + Be^{\varepsilon x})$. Then, with some initial data we have $$y = e^{-kx}\bigg(y(0) \cosh(\varepsilon x) + (y'(0) + ky(0)) \frac{\sinh(\varepsilon x)}{\varepsilon}\bigg) \to e^{-kx}\bigg(y(0) + (y'(0)+ky(0))x\bigg).$$

There are other ways. You can rewrite the equation in matrix form:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\pmatrix{y' \\ y} = \pmatrix{-2ky' - k^2 y  \\ y'} = \pmatrix{-2k & -k^2 \\ 1 & 0}\pmatrix{y' \\ y}$$

In the two-root case the matrix is diagonalisable, and the solutions given by the matrix exponential. The matrix above is not diagonalisable, and the $x$ factor arises from its Jordan Normal Form. There are details in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOK2p_vy3rI&ab_channel=BillKinney) if you're interested.

Comment: "we know that there must be two independent solutions, even without knowing what they are"; how so?

Comment: @NicolasSamanez Since the equation is linear, the set of solutions is a vector space. The number of independent solutions is the dimension of that vendor space. There are high-powered theorems that show that given $n$ boundary conditions, a degree $n$ linear homogeneous ODE has a unique solution. The boundary conditions form a space of dimension $n$, so the solutions do too. If you want a more detailed account, I recommend either searching "linear ode dimension solutions", or simply ask a new question here on MSE. It's a fact often taken without proof in early courses.

Answer (score 1):

Set
$$
z=y\mathrm{e}^{kx}
$$
Then
$$
z''=(y\mathrm{e}^{kx})''=(y'\mathrm{e}^{kx}+ky\mathrm{e}^{kx})'
=y''\mathrm{e}^{-kx}+2ky'\mathrm{e}^{-kx}+k^2y\mathrm{e}^{-kx}=(y''+2ky'+k^2y)\mathrm{e}^{-kx}=0
$$
and hence
$$
z''=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad z=c_1+c_2x\quad\Longrightarrow\quad y=(c_1+c_2x)\mathrm{e}^{-kx}
$$