# Repeated roots in exponential ansatz method of solving second order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation,

$$ y'' - 10y' + 25y=0$$

Suppose $ y = e^{rx}$, we will find $r=5$ as solution. THis suggests:

$$ y = A e^{5x}$$

But it can also be found that the family of functions of form $Bxe^{5x}$ also solves this differential equation. What exactly is the intuition behind this happening?

i.e: repeated root equations having $xe^{rx}$ also as solution?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3958865/second-order-homogeneous-differential-equations-why-do-repeated-roots-modify-th

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By variation of the constant,

$$A''(x)e^{5x}+10A'(x)e^{5x}+25A(x)e^{5x}-10A'(x)e^{5x}-50A(x)e^{5x}+25A(x)e^{5x}=0$$

or

$$A''(x)=0.$$

Then

$$A(x)=Cx+D.$$

---

An empirical explanation is that when the two roots are very close, say $r$ and $r+\delta$ with $\delta\ll$, the solution is

$$Ce^{rx}+D e^{(r+\delta)x}=(C+D e^{\delta x})e^{rx}.$$

Then plugging some initial conditions, you get

$$C+D=y_0,\\\delta D+r(C+D)=y'_0.$$

Then

$$C+De^{\delta x}=C+D+D\delta x+D\delta^2\frac{x^2}2+\cdots=y_0+(y'_0-ry_0)x+O(\delta)$$ which tends to $$y_0+(y'_0-ry_0)x.$$